# .htaccess has no effect and doesn't send expires header

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I added an `.htaccess` file to the website root folder `/var/www/html`
It looks like this

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I tried adjusting the`AllowOverride` option, as is recommended in a lot of places. 
My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
...
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

And `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` looks like this

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm fairly certain that the `.htaccess` file is just not working, because when I add random characters to the file (to try and break it and get a `500` HTTP response) it doesn't affect the website at all. 
What could be causing this?

Comment: Since your .htaccess states that it will only do anything if mod_expires is loaded: are you sure that mod_expires is loaded? `a2enmod mod_expires` might help.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @FlorianHeer and it actually was the issue!
I didn't realize I had to manually start this module. If you submit this as an answer, I will accept it. Just make sure you write down `a2enmod expires` in stead of `a2enmod mod_expires`

Comment: Thanks. I keep forgetting that 'mod_' is not necessary for `a2enmod`, I get that error message almost every time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expiry information is created and sent by the expires module. In accordance with that the `.htaccess`correctly checks for the existence of this module. If it is not loaded, no action is taken here.

Make sure that the module is loaded correctly, the currently most compatible way to do this is with `a2enmod`:

```
:~ $ a2enmod expires
```